# set up Cloud Foundry in multiple cloud controler mode

Tags: cloud-foundry

I use dev_setup  install cloud foundry with 4 nodes. One is rest node , the other is dea node ,the third is mysql0 node ,and the last is mysql1 node,But there is one cloud controler node ,that is rest node.
      How can I  set up Cloud Foundry in multiple cloud controler mode ,for example,two cloud controler nodes?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a good candidate for [Cloud Foundry Developers](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev)

Comment: I set up multiple nodes cloud foundry followed by
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/tree/master/vcap/single_and_multi_node_deployments_with_dev_setup.
Can you tell me the details of set up cloud foundry with multiple colud controllers,step by step? So I can set up it with your advice.